# Why I don't get conflict when switching branch with uncommitted changes?

Tags: git

Let's say I'm working on a **master** branch that has file *colors.txt*:

```
blue
red
yellow
```

From there I create and switch to a new branch **warm** and edit the same file *colors.txt* to:

```
red
yellow
orange
```

---

I don't add those changes to *Staging Area*, but rather switch back to **master** branch => GIT doesn't complain.

What I expected instead is message: *"Please commit your stages or stash them before you switch branches"*.

Can someone tell me how did this example succeed and why am I not getting that error message I just described?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257995/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+checkout+expected+conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you expect would only occur if your changes could not be applied to the `master` branch because it conflicts.

Otherwise uncommited changes do are kept when switching branches.

The important thing is you will never loose the changes, either you will be asked to commit/stash them before switching branch or they will be kept in the branch you switch to.

Comment: Can you tell me why would any changes not be applied to the `master` branch?

Comment: In your specific case it cannot happen. But it could happen if you created the other branch before and some commits were done in the mean time to `master`.